# Training a `BoostedTreesClassifier` in Tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am learning TensorFlow and am trying to train a `BoostedTreesClassifier` (premade estimator). However, I cannot get it to work with my bucketized columns. Below is my bucketized column:

`age_bucket_column = tf.feature_column.bucketized_column(tf.numeric_column(key='age'), [20, 40, 60])`

Here is my train input function (note features is a Pandas DataFrame):

```
def train_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))
  dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000).repeat(count=None).batch(batch_size)

  return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

Here is my estimator:

```
boosted_trees_classifier = tf.estimator.BoostedTreesClassifier(
  feature_columns=[age_bucket_column],
  n_batches_per_layer=100
)
```

And here is my code to train it:

```
classifier.train(
  input_fn=lambda: train_input_fn(train_X, train_y, 100),
  steps=1000
)
```

However, when I run it, I get the following error:
`ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype int64: 'Tensor("IteratorGetNext:13", shape=(?,), dtype=int64, device=/device:CPU:0)'`

Note that when I run the same code but with another model (say a `LinearClassifier` or `DNNClassifier`) it works perfectly. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would think that the error is with the arguments when you create the  `tf.estimator.BoostedTreesClassifier` because it isn't happening with the other two Classifiers.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of your labels are of type int64. Cast them to float32

```
train_y = pd.Series(train_y , index=np.array(range(1, train_y.shape[0] + 1)), dtype=np.float32)
```